# compare git commit to extracted directory

Tags: git

I have a git directory and another separate directory where I extracted all the files, but not the .git directory

my question is:

how do I compare a specific commit of the git directory to the files in the extracted directory?

edit:

1. I know the commit hash,
2. I cant do a git checkout because I want to leave the git directory intact
3. I have a large git tree and I need to do the diff fast as possible
4. The git directory is not necessarily checkout to the specific commit.

Answer (score 3):

You can temporarily (for the duration of the `git diff` command itself only) override Git's notion of *where* the work-tree lives:

```
git --work-tree=<path-to-tree> diff <commit>
```

Or, equivalently, from that path:

```
git --git-dir=<path-to-.git-directory> diff <commit>
```

(which uses `.` as the work-tree path while obtaining commits from the given `.git` directory).

Use whichever is most convenient.  This might even be to use *both* options.  Specifically, with `--git-dir=path`, Git will assume that the current working directory is the top level of the work-tree unless you also specify `--work-tree=top-of-work-tree`.  One or both paths may be relative to the current working directory.

(This all works with `git diff-tree`, `git diff-index`, and `git diff-files` as well, though it's probably most useful with `git diff-tree` for scripts and `git diff` for personal usage.)

Comment: almost, but: the git directory is not necessarily checkout to the commit. I tried to change the command to refer to the exact commit, but got the wrong result. this is what I tried:

    git --work-tree=<path-to-tree> diff <the commit>

Comment: That should be correct. The comparison defaults to index-vs-work-tree but if you specify a particular commit, you will compare that commit vs the work-tree. (I've updated the answer to include the `<commit>` part.)

Comment: most likely this is the correct answer, I just need time to get back to it to test that it works

Comment: @torek I just reused this solution for a different problem: comparing the state of one sandbox to the Git repo in another. It worked once I solved a gotcha: `git --git-dir=...` only works correctly if you're at the root of the sandbox. Unlike the default behaviour, Git doesn't (and clearly could not) notice that I'm in a subdirectory of my sandbox. This also works (in a subsubdirectory, e.g.): `git --git-dir=/other/sandbox/.git --work-tree=../.. diff ...`. This detail is not critical for OP's question but I think it's worth mentioning to make this question and answer more widely useful.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way I can see is to do a soft link to the `.git` directory and do `git diff <commit-SHA-1>`.

Assuming your existing Git repo is in directory A, and the extracted files are in directory B, you can do the following:

```
cd B
ln -s ../A/.git
git diff <commit-SHA-1>
```

Warning: don't do any commits or any operations that could modify the contents of `.git` in B, because you might corrupt A in the process. Or maybe not corrupt it, but anything you do in B would affect what Git sees in A, anyway.

Comment: that might work but the cloning would take too long. I want the enitre operation to be as fast as possible

Comment: The cloning is not part of the solution: you only need the two last lines, the rest was to show you how I am simulating your situation. I will edit my answer to make that clear.

Comment: Of course, the answer given by @torek is even better, but I have tested it and my solution works well too, with the difference that it associates that `.git` folder for all Git commands, not just the `git diff` itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the wanted commit, it'll update the working tree to the state where the files where at this point of the codebase history :

```
git checkout <commit-SHA-1>
```

If you don't know the specific SHA-1 hash, you can find it in the log (`git log`).

This way, you'll be able to sequentially checkout different commits and compare each of them with your unchanging separate version.

Comment: thanks, but I cant do a git checkout because I want to leave the git directory intact 0 see edit to the question

Comment: @yigal Maybe consider cloning your git repo in another (local) directory, then checkout on *this* last one?

Comment: that might work but the cloning would take too long. I want the enitre operation to be as fast as possible